# How to divide a method into sub-methods effectively?

Tags: java

So basically what this thread boils down to is that I want some private methods to just represent a block of code inside another method. I'm aware of how scoping works in Java but there are times where I wish things worked differently:

Suppose I have a method *doLotsOfStuff()* in my class that does more than one thing. Naturally one would divide the things into several methods *doThis()* and *doThat()* of type *VOID*. You encounter problems of this kind:

1) I can no longer operate on any data defined in  *doLotsOfStuff()* in either *doThis()* and *doThat()* without first passing all the necessary arguments needed, which would not make them void! For example *doThis(int doLotsOfStuffsInt)* This means that if I want a chain of calls, the same **variable must be passed** along throughout in a line of arguments. ..which leads to this:

2) *doThis()* and *doThat()* set as private would still be visible for all other methods in the same class, even though I just want to use them for *doLotsOfStuff()*. Having a long chain of sub methods that are only meant to be used a single time will now clutter up the whole Class.

Here is what I wish existed: 
a,b,c,d are private methods in the same class. The -> indicates a call to a method.

**a() -> b() -> c()**

c() can use variables from a() or b() freely without passing the arguments around down the chain.

**d() -/-> c()**

c() cannot be called by d() as c() is only "local" to a() and any of its subsequent callers.

Consider the short example:

```
private void someMethod()
{
    char a = 'a';
    printA();
}


private void printA() {
    System.out.println(a);  //a cannot resolve, but I don't want to pass it as an argument from someMethod()!
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this, without having to pass a as an argument? Some sort of declaration in the lines of 
"private void printA() dependson someMethod"?

Wouldn't this be a good functionality to have? If not, why? How would you do it?

Comment: Maybe a [method object](http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceMethodWithMethodObject.html) fits your needs?

Comment: I am no expert to JVM stuff but i would argue that at execution time there is little difference in the efficiency of `printA(int a)` vs `printA()` using member variable. When it comes to readability and reduction of clutter, consider using an inner class.

Comment: You are trying the redefine the scope rules as far as I can understand. I guess you already know this, but if you want to avoid passing the variable "a" to printA() you would have to define "a" in the scope of the class. Regarding "c() cannot be called by d() as c() is only "local" to a() and any of its callers". This is against the visibility rules defined in java. Maybe the experts can correct me, but this does not exist in java.

Comment: Maybe some variation of this: http://www.jayway.com/2012/02/07/builder-pattern-with-a-twist/

Comment: @RC. Because if I have many blocks of code in a larger method I just want to separate them into VOID sub-methods that depend on the callers variables. Then there's the example I brought up of passing the same variable across a chain of methods calls.

Comment: I would recommend you to complete a good read on defining instance, class and local variable and the scope of them. That should make things clear for you.

Comment: There are programming languages having this feature, Java does not belong to them.

Comment: Are you really talking about wanting [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29)? In fact, you may also be talking about [nested functions](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/nested-functions.html) in languages like scala -  although that also doesn't quite fit your description.

Comment: If you have long methods in a class that have their own state (variables) you like to break up, and are concerned about cluttering the class they are in, probably it is a good idea to think about splitting your class first into multiple classes... An extreme case is a **method object** that is a class for what was previously one method, but perhaps some code in your method is shared with another method, so probably it is a better idea to extract both of them to the same new class...

Answer (score 3):

#### What you are looking for is called [Closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) scoping:

`Closures` are not natively supported in `Java` and honestly not very elegant to imitate. This ability is native in most dynamic languages like `Groovy` or `JavaScript`

A [`Closure`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) captures the variables in a scope of its definition.

[If you use `final` references](http://www.vertigrated.com/blog/2011/05/the-final-word-on-final/) you can refer to them in inner classes and **mimic the behavior of data hiding** in a `Closure`with an inner class.

#### [Q32766010.java](https://github.com/jarrodhroberson/Stack-Overflow/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stackoverflow/Q32766010.java)

```
public class Q32766010
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final Example e = new Example();
        e.doSomething(23,42);
    }

    public static class Example
    {
        public void doSomething(final int a, final int b)
        {
            class ClosureLikeThing {
                ClosureLikeThing doThis() { System.out.println("a = " + a); return this; }
                ClosureLikeThing doThat() { System.out.println("b = " + b); return this; }
            }
            new ClosureLikeThing().doThis().doThat();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Outputs

```
a = 23
b = 42
```

#### This hides the inner details from the public interface.

This will do the data/method hiding you are looking for. It is a
*Method Object* pattern implementation of sorts and might trip up new programmers because it is not used very often in Java.  This kind of inner class usage is prevalent in more dynamic languages like Python, JavaScript and Ruby.

This can help declutter your code in a good IDE that supports code folding. If you set your IDE to fold all inner classes it will make the source less
*noisy*.

More lines of code is not always bad, if you make it easier to automatically refactor something using a tool like Intellij IDEA easier then more lines of code is better because it can be maintained automatically.

A few more lines of code to narrow the scope of something is almost always better. The narrower the scope the less side effects that are possible and the easier to maintain and debug because what effects that code and what that code effects are minimal and explicitly obvious because of the narrow scope.

This idiom is used in Java mostly for things like `Iterator` and `FluentBuilder` pattern implementations to hide the details of the implementation. Here is an example ['UrlBuilder'](http://www.vertigrated.com/blog/2015/08/fluent-builder-pattern-revisited/).

#### Alternative using Interfaces if you have multiple implementations:

This works the same way but will allow you to create multiple implementations if you need different behavior from the same `Interface`.

```
public static class Example
{
    interface ClosureLikeThing
    {
        public ClosureLikeThing doThis();

        public ClosureLikeThing doThat();
    }

    public void doSomething(final int a, final int b)
    {
        new ClosureLikeThing()
        {
            @Override
            public ClosureLikeThing doThis()
            {
                System.out.println("a = " + a);
                return this;
            }

            @Override
            public ClosureLikeThing doThat()
            {
                System.out.println("b = " + b);
                return this;
            }
        }.doThis().doThat();
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting choice in class name

Comment: The OP wants to split up big methods to reduce clutter. I dont think closures are appropriate, they somehow resemble what the OP was asking for in terms of special scoping, but certainly don't lead to uncluttered code.

Comment: this is not a closure it is a very common Java idiom, inner classes that provide closure like scoping, and it does declutters the public interface of the outer class and hides the data and implemenation.

Comment: @JamesWierzba Class name refers to the URL, a good idea if you  quickly want to find the source question !

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I didn't quite get the part about using final references, As far as I know, the final only makes the object immutable. I'll have to read on about that.. thanks!

Comment: @starbyone - `final` does **not** make an object immutable, it makes the reference to an object instance immutable. [Here is a good article on how and why to use `final` and why it is so important.](http://www.vertigrated.com/blog/2011/05/the-final-word-on-final/)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson thanks for again pointing it out in your answer, i get it now and try to incorporate it in future work! :)

Answer (score 2):

If a method is so complex that even splitting it in sub methods and passing arguments clutters up the class, it's probably a good sign that you need to delegate to another stateful class.

For example:

```
private void someMethod() {
    ComplexPrinter printer = ComplexPrinter('a');
    printer.foo();
    printer.bar();
    printer.baz();
}
```

Or at least, to avoid passing too many arguments to each method, to store them in a single context object:

```
private void someMethod() {
    PrintContext context = PrintContext('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
    foo(context);
    bar(context);
    baz(context);
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i wanted to suggest, no need for me to finish typing! :)
If you can't find a better OOP class model for your software and have truly seperated concerns, it might just be a complex function alltogether and doesn't need any splitting but better comments?
If splitting makes sense, but your context is too big, in C you would probably create a struct. In Java, just create a proxy class for your contexts, or use a `HashMap<String, Object>`

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Seelenvirtuose's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766010/java-how-to-divide-a-method-into-sub-methods-effectively#comment53371103_32766010):
You can create a "method object", to whose constructor you pass all the arguments, which you can then use freely in any of its methods:

Suppose you have:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private void someMethod()
    {
        char a = 'a';
        char b = 'b';
        char c = 'c';
        System.out.println(a);
        /* Lots of code here */
        System.out.println(b);
        /* More lots of more code here */
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

You could turn it into:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private void someMethod()
    {
        LongMethod lm = new LongMethod('a', 'b', 'c');
        lm.printA();
        lm.printB();
        lm.printC();
    }

    private static class LongMethod
    {
        private char a;
        private char b;
        private char c;

        public LongMethod(char a, char b, char c)
        {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = c;
        }

        public void printA()
        {
            /* A third of a lot of code here */
            System.out.println(a);
        }

        public void printB()
        {
            /* A third of a lot of code here */
            System.out.println(b);
        }

        public void printC()
        {
            /* A third of a lot of code here */
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though the print() methods are in fact void as I want, I still have to pass arguments into the constructor and create a new class, which to me is no different than just having three methods that take a,b,c accordingly as arguments. Thanks for your contribution though, It does give me new perspectives.

Comment: With a constructor you have to pass them only once, as opposed to passing them to every method separately. For three methods this won't make too much of a difference, but I think that looks different for 20 methods or so. Either way, this is probably the closes you'll get to share variables across multiple methods. Might I also suggest that you rename your question to "Share variables across multiple methods" or something like that? I think it would describe your problem more precisely than the current title. (And I know I could change it myself, but I'd consider that rude in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

What you are proposing goes against the paradigm in most programming languages called ***scope***.

The reason the method exists is to encapsulate a piece of functionality of a larger program to make it understandable and re-usable.

It is good to break up a big method to make it understandable (even if you only call the method once), but if you find yourself needing access to lots of variables in the original big method, I would question if it is really necessary to break it up.

If the language allowed methods to access variables in other methods, it would become a nightmare to keep track of what is going on in your program.

I found this funny analogy on the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Programming/Scope) and I think it applies well here.

> Imagine that you have a really nice collection of tools—really nice.
>   Now imagine that you decide to lend your tools to any neighbor who
>   asks. Unless you have exceptional neighbors, you will probably find it
>   necessary to modify this policy eventually because some of those tools
>   will end up broken and others will disappear forever without a trace.

Comment: Java does allow you to access variable references in other classes and methods from inner classes if the references are `final` this is very common with `Listener` type Interfaces that have anonymous inner class implementations that can access all the variables in the parents scope, even `private` ones.

Comment: Yes that is an option, but OP's exact words were "a,b,c,d are private methods in the same class"

Comment: technically inner classes especially `package private` ones belong to the scope of the parent outer class which is why all the private stuff is available to them.

Comment: Yes they share scope but they are not the same class